# Advantage of installing VMs on dedicated vs native?

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, dedicated-server

If I were to buy a dedicated server, what is the advantage of installing 4 VMs for 4 services (mail, Web, Database, Cache/other) vs installing everything on the dedicated server?

Or is it more for reselling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+Manageability. +Isolation. +Portability.

Comment: Duh - Yeah ok I see it. I forgot kernel updates, system errors, etc. At least not all services are down. Thanks!

Comment: Throw in one more physical host, add some shared storage (StarWind vSAN Free?), and you’ll be able to improve uptime and usability dramatically.

Comment: So 2 dedicated servers with a couple of web servers on each. Got it thanks! (I cannot upvote yet but I eventually will ;)) I'll DDG StarWind vSAN. You are awesome